# Unified way in Rake to work with arguments passed by #invoke and #execute

Tags: ruby, rake

I expected a Task to get arguments the same way, transparent to the caller methods `#invoke` or `#execute`:

```
desc "Add task"
task :add do |t, args|
  puts args.class
  puts "Add"
end

desc "Sub task"
task :sub do |t, args|
  puts args.class
  puts "Sub"
end

desc "all"
task :all do
  Rake::Task['add'].execute("arg1") # cannot set multiple arguments, will fail with "wrong number of arguments"
  Rake::Task['sub'].invoke("arg1", "arg2")
end
```

The result was:

```
» rake all
String
Add
Rake::TaskArguments
Sub
```

Upon checking the Rake source code it is clear these implementations are different.

Is there an unified way to manage arguments regardless where they come from? (command line, #invoke or #execution?). I use OptParse for the command line arguments so I have two ugly workarounds in my code now.

Answer (score 0):

i assume that in case of `execute` if number of arguments > 1 then you want to `execute` with an argument is an array collect all those arguments, otherwise `execute` will execute with nil or the only input argument (a String, for example). So the way you call `execute` will match with the way you call `invoke` and `execute` still do the same as origin.

you could create a wrapper (alias) for `Rake::Task#execute` and handle the input arguments as below

```
# Rakefile
Rake::Task.alias_method :old_execute, :execute
Rake::Task.define_method("execute") do |*args|
  if args&.size > 1
    old_execute(args)
  else
    old_execute(args&.first)
  end
end

# ...

Rake::Task['add'].execute # Rake::TaskArguments
Rake::Task['add'].execute("arg1") # String
Rake::Task['add'].execute("arg1", "arg2") # Array
```